# "Sling Blade Runner": efficient algorithm to find chain of overlapping movie titles?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

This problem is from the [archived puzzle from ITA Software](http://www.itasoftware.com/careers/puzzle_archive.html), Since the puzzle is retired I guess it is ok to discuss.

> How long a chain of overlapping movie titles, like "Live and Let Die Another Day of the Dead Poet's Society", can you find?

I would like to know what is the best approach/algorithm to solve such puzzle.

Comment: The original question has more subtleties not mentioned here: "Multi-word overlaps, as in "License to Kill a Mockingbird," are allowed. The same title may not be used more than once in a solution. Heuristic solutions that may not always produce the greatest number of titles will be accepted: seek a reasonable tradeoff of efficiency and optimality."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a graph problem.

First you build a graph, where each vertex represents a movie. There is an edge (a,b) if the movie a end in the same word as the one with which the movie b starts.

Now you want to find the longest path in the graph. This is NP-complete problem, so it doesn't have polynomial solution. ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem))

Comment: Although this will be a directed graph, and if it is acyclic then it _can_ be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: true, but it's not acyclic, obviously

Comment: Although in this specific case if it contains a cycle then the longest chain is infinite, so the program can check for cycles using Bellman-Ford before searching for the longest path while maintaining polynomial time.

Comment: true again, but I assumed that you are not allowed to use the same movie twice...

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. That would make much more sense haha

Comment: A trivial cycle: "Dead of night of the living dead [of night...]"